# Изменение порядка сортировки Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

допустим есть таблица 'table1' которая содержит одну колонку 'num' тип int в этой колонке порядковые числа от 1 до 1000. Задача, SELECT должен отдавать выборку в которое первой строкой будет поле 'num' равное 643, а далее содержать остальную часть таблицы. Дальнейшая сортировка поля 'num' не важна, но полученный SELECT должен содержать всю 1000 строк. База Postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select *
from table1
order by
  case num when 643 then 0 else 1 end
```

Comment: Очень признателен.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
ORDER BY num <> 643
```

Если в поле присутствуют NULL - они будут выведены слитной группой в самом конце.

Comment: Спасибо за потраченное время